# Rotate text on th Y axis

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-transforms

In the last few days I played around with the CSS transform Property a bit and I want to find a way for perspectives, like this:

[image: several texte boxes rotated on the Y axis]

With the Boxes all being normal rectangular boxes. I just have no idea where to start.

As requested:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.skewed {
  margin: -1px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: perspective(200px) rotateY(45deg);
}
.skewed > img {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale") blur(3px);
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) blur(3px);
  /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.skewed:hover > img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="skewed">
  <img src="image001.jpg">
</div>
<div class="skewed">
  <img src="image002.jpg">
</div>
<div class="skewed">
  <img src="image003.jpg">
</div>
<div class="skewed">
  <img src="image004.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried ... at least the html and basic css for those boxes.

Comment: Those boxes are put together with GIMP, I tried pretty much all transform properties but none lead me to this result, even combinations so, as stated, I have no Idea where to start.

Comment: Start with a basic html and CSS to make those boxes.

Comment: I'm sorry, It seems you don't understand my problem. I just want to know which transform property I am supposed to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty simple with [CSS 3d transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). You can rotate each element on the Y axis with `transform:rotateY(xdeg);`

Here is an example :

```css
div {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 7em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.1em 0;
  text-align: center;
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(30deg);
  background: teal;
}
div:nth-child(2n) {
  transform: perspective(500px) rotateY(-30deg);
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
<div>some text</div>
```

*Note that you will need to add vendor prefixes for browser support. See [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) for more info*